# c++ check xs:double datatype

Tags: c++, gcc

I have data of the following form:

```
x="12.847.E.89"
y="12-1.2344e56"
```

Now I want to find out whether x and y confirm to xs:double data type http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#double. That they may have exactly one decimal and E, one + or - at the beginning of the string, also it may have any number of alphanumeric characters. E.g. here, y is an xs:double data type while x is not an xs:double  data type.

I know I can check whether each character is present in a string or not using: x.find('.'),etc. But this gives me only if a character is present or not. It does not give me a way to specify or check that no other character apart form .,+,-,E are present and E,+,- themselves appear once and in conformance with xs:double data type. Is it possible do the same in C++ using any standard library function.

gcc version which I am using is: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.4-6ubuntu2) 4.6.4

Comment: This is a case where *regular expressions* should work fine.

Comment: You can use [`stod()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ok..thanks a lot..can u please explain this with an example

Comment: @NathanOliver But it does not let me check..please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You didn't read carefully: `Exceptions. If no conversion could be performed, an invalid_argument exception is thrown. If the value read is out of the range of representable values by a double (in some library implementations, this includes underflows), an out_of_range exception is thrown.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`stod()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/) takes a second parameter that gives the number of characters it was able to convert.  You can use this to see if the whole string was converted or not.  Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::string good = "-1.2344e56";
    std::string bad = "12.847.E.89";
    std::string::size_type endPosition;

    double goodDouble = std::stod(good, &endPosition);
    if (endPosition == good.size())
        std::cout << "string converted is: " << goodDouble << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "string cannot be converted";

    double badDouble = std::stod(bad, &endPosition);
    if (endPosition == good.size())
        std::cout << "string converted is: " << badDouble << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "string cannot be converted";

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

If no conversion could be performed, an invalid_argument exception is thrown. If the value read is out of the range of representable values by a double (in some library implementations, this includes underflows), an out_of_range exception is thrown.

Comment: Ooops..I am getting the  error: ‘stod’ is not a member of ‘std’. Actually I am not working with C++11. It needs c++ 11

Comment: Yes this does require C++11.  C++11 is over 4 years old including C++0x now so you should be using it.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.4-6ubuntu2) 4.6.4

Comment: have you to tried compiling with `-std=c++0x`?  Better yet why not update gcc, they are up to 4.9.2 now.

Comment: If I activate this, then other errors start coming in my project

Comment: If you can't use C++11 then you can look at [`strtod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/).  It behaves similarly to `stod()`.  I would suggest that you start codding in C++11 though since there are many features that have been added to the language that are quite useful.

Comment: Thanks for all the help :) I tried the function: bool isDouble(string& doubleString)
{
    //std::string::size_type endPosition;   
    char* endPosition;
    //strto
    std::strtod(doubleString.c_str(), &endPosition);
    if (endPosition == doubleString.c_str())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
but it does not seem to work